# Mounting Linux volume on second disk

Tags: linux, fedora, mount, hard-drive

The disk on my Fedora 12 box was starting to fail, so I bought a new disk and installed Fedora 15. I kept the old disk connected, which still sort of works, hoping to copy over some important files.

In Fedora 15, the "Disk Utility" application lets me mount the /boot partition, but not 
the other volume on the old disk. "Disk Utility" shows the existence of that volume, but doesn't offer a way to mount it.

Here's what it says in the old /etc/fstab for the old root and /boot:

/dev/mapper/vg_flotsam-lv_root /                       ext4    defaults        1 1
UUID=f88eefec-a42f-4797-b704-bb1a426b8874 /boot        ext4    defaults        1 2

How can I mount the old volume?

Comment: This is complicated slightly (and on the other hand, made easier :) ) by the fact that you appear to be using LVM.  Can you edit your post with the output of the following commands:  pvscan, vgscan, and lvscan?

Answer (score 1):

As the root partition on the old disk is using LVM the first thing to do is to make sure that the system has found all the physical volumes by running `pvscan` as root - you shouldn't need to give it any arguments.

Then run `vgscan` as root, again with no arguments, and you should see the `vg_flotsam` volume group listed in the output.

Make sure the volume group is activated by running `vgchange -a y vg_flotsam` as root and you should find that the `/dev/mapper/vg_flotsam-lv_root` device will appear and you will then be able to mount it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the logical volumes on both disks was the same. By renaming one of them, I was able to mount the volume on the old disk and copy the data.

Comment: If you're the OP, you might want to log in as them and mark this answer as accepted.